# trying to use operator() error comp cannot be used c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, sorting, functor

I have class sort pointer, and class sortID that inherits from it.
class sortID has operator(), and im trying to send it to this function trying to sort my list. it gives me error:
"sort cannot be used as a function."

```
#include "Sort.h"
#include "SortID.h"
class Movie{


list<int*> somelist;
public:
void Movie::sortList()
{
  Sort* sorter = new sortID();
  this->someList.sort(sorter);
}
}
```

this is class sortID:

```
#include "sort.h"
class SortID : public Sort {


bool sortID::operator()(const int* a, const int* b){
return a.getId() < b.getId();
}

class Sort{
public:
virtual bool operator()(const int* a, const int* b)=0;
```

HELP..?

Comment: Why are you putting `#include` directives *inside* the classes? What does the `sort.h` and `sortid.h` header files look like? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And please show us the complete and unedited build log.

Comment: Go and use the STL: std::sort is all you need

Comment: @bebbo `std::list` has a `sort` member function. It's more efficient than `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

`list::sort` does not want a pointer.
Just pass an object:

```
void Movie::sortList()
{
  someList.sort(SortID());
}
```

(There are other errors in the code you posted, but I guess those are caused by you retyping when you should have copied and pasted.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `somelist` variable is of type `list<int*>`, not of type `list<SortID*>`.

Your compiler does not know you have a pointer to a SortID class stored there, therefore can not recognize the `()` operator.

You can either change your list type:

```
list<SortID*> somelist;
```

Or cast it when being called - not safe though:

```
((SortID*) this->someList).sort(sorter);
```